# Injecting Implementations From Another Gradle Module in Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use hilt to inject an implementation of a repository class(the interface lives in the `domain` module, the implementation in the `data` module with the `data` module depending on the `domain` one) but receiving an error when building the app. Here's my setup

In `domain` module

```
interface RatesRepository {
    fun getRates(): Single<Rates>
}
```

in `data` module

```
class RatesRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val rateDataSource: CurrencyExchangeDataSource,
    private val mapper: ExchangeResponseToRates
) : RatesRepository {
//..
}

@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
interface DataModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindsRatesRepository(ratesRepositoryImpl: RatesRepositoryImpl): RatesRepository
}
```

and data declares domain as a dependency

EDIT:
the error I'm receiving :

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.basil.domain_converter.repository.RatesRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class ApplicationC implements CurrenciesApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.basil.domain_converter.repository.RatesRepository is injected at
          com.basil.domain_converter.usecase.GetRatesUseCase(ratesRepository)
      javax.inject.Provider<com.basil.domain_converter.usecase.GetRatesUseCase> is injected at
          com.basil.ui_converter.ui.RatesViewModel_AssistedFactory(getRatesUseCase)
      com.basil.ui_converter.ui.RatesViewModel_AssistedFactory is injected at
          com.basil.ui_converter.ui.RatesViewModel_HiltModule.bind(arg0)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>> is injected at
          androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule.provideFactory(…, viewModelFactories)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory java.util.Set<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.ActivityEntryPoint.getActivityViewModelFactory() [com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.ApplicationC → com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.FragmentEntryPoint.getFragmentViewModelFactory() [com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.ApplicationC → com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC → com.basil.example.CurrenciesApp_HiltComponents.FragmentC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Plausible explanation

It seems you have a problem with your `Scopes`.

You're `Installing` your `RatesRepository` in the `FragmentComponent`, but you're trying to use it in the dependencies of a higher level. I can see you're trying to inject `RatesRepository` in `ViewModels`, and `ViewModels` [do not relate to `FragmentComponent` but `ActivityRetainedComponent`](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#generated-components).

See [this graph](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-hierarchy):
[image: component hierarchy]

---

### Solution

I would expect a `Repository` should be maintained in the `App` scope, so I would modify your setup to:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface DataModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindsRatesRepository(ratesRepositoryImpl: RatesRepositoryImpl): RatesRepository
}
```

If dependencies of `RatesRepositoryImpl` have narrower scope, you can try `ActivityRetainedComponent` instead of `ApplicationComponent`.