# API interface dependency injection with hilt

Tags: android, kotlin

I am newbie at dagger hilt.

I have created implementation, where I inject my constructor such as :

```
class ListItemsPagingSourceFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val api: Api,
    private val pageErrorsQueue: ListItemsPagingErrorsQueue
) {

}
```

```
interface Api {

    fun getList(
        count: Int,
        offset: Int
    ) : ListItemResponse
```

I have an error with my api interface I only want to implement my methods to be used later.
However error occurs like:

```
Error: [Hilt]
public abstract interface Api {
                ^
```

When I added
@InstallIn
@EntryPoint

To Api inteface:

```
error: [Hilt]
  @InstallIn, 'value' class is invalid or missing: @dagger.hilt.InstallIn({})
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

EDIT:
I have very similar implementation, but with retrofit where I use (@Get,@Query etc) I would like to implement my own "API" that is just method which get data locally from service without launching database.
This is code from retrofitApi

```
interface RetrofitApi {
    @GET("data/mine")
    suspend fun getDataItems(
        @Query("count") count: Int,
        @Query("size") size: Int
    ): DataItemsResponse
```

How to change it as just interface or abstract class, which has got only methods without launching DB =>  to not have Dagger screams in the log.

EDIT2:

This configuration doesn't work as well.

```
@InstallIn
@Module(includes = [AppModule.Api::class])
class AppModule {
    // interface with @Binds
    @Module
    interface Api {
        @Binds
        fun getList(
            count: Int,
            offset: Int
        ) : ListItemResponse
    }
}
```

error:

```
@Binds methods must have exactly one parameter, whose type is assignable to the return type
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since API is an abstract interface, you wouldn't add those annotations there.  You'd add them to the concrete implementation.  Whatever class has those Dagger needs to be able to instantiate, and it can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: what do you mean to the concrete implementation? To concrete methods?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100410/what-is-concrete-implementation. A non abstract implementation-  an actual implementation that can be instantiated.  When you inject a type in your system, something somewhere need to provide the implementation.  That provided implementation must be concrete-  it must define all of those abstract functions.

Comment: Thank you so much I have understood this well. I cannot @Provides any inteface, but instead of this I could use abstract class or just normal class to provide but I think it is not my case. Instead of this I still would like to use interface, but I;m not sure how to make it to not have Dagger scream at me. I would like to kindly ask you to write your suggestion and look at my edit above in main post ,please.

I do not need implementation with direct method like class with method {}, I would like to use here interface.

Comment: I checked this example but still doesn;t work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625370/injecting-implementations-from-another-gradle-module-in-hilt

Comment: and here is sth interesting I am just trying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618763/dagger2-how-to-use-provides-and-binds-in-same-module